# How do I anchor sections?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a document with a lot of different 'chapters'. I want to have footnotes restart at every chapter which I figure I can accomplish by adding sections for each chapter. However, I want the sections to be anchored to certain text, for example the chapter title. That way, if I delete or add a bunch of text before the new section, it will move the section marker with it.

> Example: the section marker is on page 8 and I remove all the text from page 6. I now want the section marker to move to page 7.

How do I do this?

Extra: if possible it would be even better if I could use GREP to automatically add sections every time a certain paragraph style is used (for example a command that would add a section marker before the text in the paragraph style 'Chapter title').

Comment: Are all your text frames threaded? Or do you start a new article when starting a new section? About your extra question, Grep can't achieve that. You need a script - or a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: All the text frames are linked. The whole document is one big story.

Comment: Hmmm... That's what I was afraid of... Imho, the easiest way would be to split your stories. No need for sections anymore nor for the "restart footnote numbering" option. Make sure Smart text reflow is set up to add pages at the end of the story and that delete blank pages is checked. To split stories, you might find Adi Ravid's storysplitter.jsx useful.